# How can I obtain size of largest list out of list of lists using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Say I am having following list of lists"

```
List l1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
List l2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List l3 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
List<List> lists = Arrays.asList(l1,l2,l3);
```

How can I know size of largest list using Java 8 streams API?
I thought, something like this will work:

```
lists.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, (a,b) -> Integer.max(a.size(), b.size()));
```

But for obvious reasons, it is giving me:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to List
```

How can I do above using Java 8 streams? (And also if there is any other better approach possible)

Also can I get reference to list with max size?

Comment: Unrelated: you are using raw types here, even mixing a generic and a raw type. That is super bad practice. Dont use raw types, even when just giving examples! It also helps a lot in terms of getting your ide to suggest the correct set of available methods, return types, etc.

Answer (score 20):

You can just call `max`:

```
lists.stream().mapToInt(List::size).max().getAsInt()
```

And to take the list with the highest size:

```
lists.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(List::size)).get()
```

Comment: and what about if I want reference to list having max size?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Added that to the answer

Answer (score 6):

If you need to know only the size, but not the list itself.

```
List l1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
List l2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List l3 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
List<List> lists = Arrays.asList(l1,l2,l3);
lists.stream().map(List::size).max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you ever get stuck with < Java8, a simple loop should suffice:

```
int max = 0;
for (List list : lists) {
    if (list.size() > max) {
        max = list.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the longest list with reduce you can do:

```
    Optional<List> list=lists.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a.size()>b.size()? a:b);
```

This reduces your list of strings to a single list based on size (that list being Optional). To print its size you can do:

```
    list.ifPresent((a)-> System.out.println(a.size()));
```

Or a one liner would be:

```
    lists.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a.size()>b.size()? a:b).ifPresent((a)-> System.out.println(a.size()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map operation to get the size rather than a reduce one, then you can find the maximum with the built-in method `max` (which returns an `OptionalInt`, so you use `get` to return an `int`)

```
lists.stream().mapToInt(x -> x.size()).max().getAsInt()
```